# Using GraphQL to join MySQL tables on different servers?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, graphql, apollo-server

I have 2 MySQL servers. I need to make select queries where I join tables on different servers. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM server1.table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN server2.table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
WHERE t1.my_field = 'some value'
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 100 ORDER BY t1.my_field;
```

I have read a lot of articles, theoretically, it's possible to add a few data sources to GraphQL (for example Apollo server) but I can't find any example of this or even any clear answer - if this possible or not? Please advice. Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: I have never seen this done... i think you would have to use the resultset from one server and filter on the other... easy to setup diff connection, but one connection to two servers... i doubt you are gonna find an example of that...

Comment: @GregBelyea thank you for your answer. do you know any tool to make queries from example work?

Comment: Do you have an ORM in mind, i know something like Prisma will allow you to be up and going quickly, but i use sequelize which requires a little more boilerplate but is a very well documented and there is a pile of knowledge on here and questions answered when it comes to that

Comment: @GregBelyea thank you for advice! I'm using standart java stack in my web app - spring, hibernate etc

Comment: then you may find this link helpful... https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-examples/tree/master/hibernate-example

Comment: But if you are simply looking for GraphQL to solve the problem you have above, I think you are barking up the wrong tree... you could probably just do that with multiple hibernate connections and custom queries...

Comment: @GregBelyea yeah. I already understood that I need to do this manually or have some data warehouse with ETL process. thank you for help!